# Should .NET thread-pool create the minimum amount of worker threads at start-up?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, multithreading, threadpool

Given an ASMX service application hosted on Windows server 2008r2, IIS 7.5, integrated pool, .net 4.0 CLR, 64-bit. It is almost asynchronous and widely use TPL library.

**Is it correct to assume that .NET thread-pool minimum worker threads configured to be N forces N worker threads creation at start-up?**

I'm expecting this behavior but it does not happen or happens intermittently.

Here are details on configuration:
Machine.config  section has its attribute 'minWorkerThreads' set to 100, in order to init thread-pool with minimum 100*CPUcount (let's say 400 for 4 core desktop) worker threads.

Just after service application start ThreadPool.**GetMinThreads**(out minWorkerThreadsCount, out minIoThreadsCount) shows as expected that ***minWorkerThreadsCount* is 400**.

Despite this fact **Debug 'Threads' window shows only 60 threads** the same as Task manager. It seems like thread-pool falls back to the default behavior, but  *minWorkerThreadsCount* is still 400.

**Any ideas of what can trigger such behavior or decrease the number of threads at run-time?** 
Allegedly this issue appears when application was build in .NET 4.5 run-time targeting .NET 4.0.

I would appreciate any input.

Comment: What exactly is your problem? Do you expect more performance if you have 100 times more threads than cores? Or are you just curious?

Comment: @AloisKraus actually I want to know thread pool behaviour on start-up in order to make right assumptions. Up to your question. Is it more perfomant to have the same number of threads as cores when service makes 1K I/O calls per second on blocking sockets?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. It will grow quickly up to that number rather than start with that many threads.

See part of [ThreadPool.SetMinThreads](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadpool.setminthreads(v=vs.110).aspx) I highligted:

> Sets the minimum number of threads the thread pool **creates on demand, as new requests are made**, before switching to an algorithm for managing thread creation and destruction.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. Under test load threads count grows fast up to MinThreads count and does not drop below this value later.